# Concurrency::create_task throws runtime exception in VisualStudio clr project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I'm new in VisualStudio and visual c++. I'm trying to use Concurrency::create_task function in MFC project.

I created clr prject, created simple form and create new class to manage tasks.
And i had to set **Common Language Runtime Support** to **No Common Language RunTime Support** to use tasks in this class.

Class header **testtest.h**:

```
#pragma once
class testtest
{
public:
    testtest();
};
```

and **testtest.cpp**:

```
#include "testtest.h"
#include <ppltasks.h>

using namespace Concurrency;

testtest::testtest()
{
    auto task1 = create_task([]() -> int
    {
        return 42;
    });
}
```

When i launch my app, it throws runtime exception (i don't even create testtest class instance)

```
Program: C:\projects\c\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 1037

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)
```

Everything works fine if i create win32 console project.
Spent a lot of time to reolve this, but now i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you look in the file `debug_heap.cpp, line 1037` and see what's there?

Comment: @SteveWellens: You already know what's there: `_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)`. And how does this help? If you send an e-mail to a non-existant recipient, it's not going to help you much to debug the mail server, right? What does help is inspecting the call stack at the point where the assertion fails.

Comment: @SteveWellens: assertion fails in **utility.cpp**
`extern "C" _onexit_t __cdecl _onexit(_onexit_t const function)
{
    _PVFV* const onexit_first = __crt_fast_decode_pointer(module_local_atexit_table._first);

    if (onexit_first == reinterpret_cast<_PVFV*>(-1))
    {
        return _crt_atexit(reinterpret_cast<_PVFV>(function)) == 0
            ? function
            : nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return _register_onexit_function(&module_local_atexit_table, function) == 0
            ? function
            : nullptr;
    }
}`
exactly on `_register_onexit_function` line

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
testtest::testtest()
{
    auto task1 = create_task([]() -> int
    {
        return 42;
    });
}
```

contains a race: the task object is created, the task is run, meanwhile the function exits and the destructor is called.

To remove the race, use [`wait` or `get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx#task-class):

```
testtest::testtest()
{
    auto task1 = create_task([]() -> int
    {
        return 42;
    });

    // Uncomment one of the following
    // task1.get();
    // task1.wait();
}
```

---

A race is, well, a race - changing the build conditions (or basically anything else), can change how it runs. Race conditions should be eliminated.